# Create Java List From Recursive SQL Query

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, collections, recursive-query

I have a record that I need to do some validation on. This record can potentially have multiple children. I need to create a collection (I was planning on using a standard list) containing the ID of every child record but this needs to be recursive (i.e. each child record can also have child records of its own, and I need each of those IDs as well, ad infinitem).I'm using MSSQL Server for my DB but I'm not too sure how I would structure the necessary SQL query.

This is what I have tried;

```
DECLARE @Id VARCHAR(30) = '[Record Id]';
WITH cte AS 
 (
  SELECT record.id, record.parentid
  FROM records r
  WHERE id = @Id
  UNION ALL
  SELECT record.id, wo.parentid
  FROM records r JOIN cte c ON wo.parentid = c.id
  )
  SELECT id
  FROM cte;
```

I get the following error:

The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.

Comment: What *have* you tried. What about it didn't work? There are plenty of examples of recursive queries out there, including on this site. Which of those did you look at, and what about them did you not understand?

Comment: You've tagged Java and SQL Server here too; what language are you looking for a solution in? If you show us what you have so far, that'll tell us the correct language.

Comment: Sorry that probably wasn't clear re the language. I'll be making a query to the SQL DB from inside a Java class, the java side of things should be fine it's really the SQL that I'm not sure about. I'll edit my original response.